# How can I refer to properties from a struct within a struct/

Tags: swift, class, struct, swiftui

I'm trying to get the hang of how to make my code the most efficient using Structs / Classes, and I'm trying to understand it via the following example.

I'd be really grateful if someone could correct me or guide me about the same:

Just as an example, I'll use Harry Potter. There are four houses, and each house has certain characteristics.

So now I have a struct for 2 of them:

```
struct Gryffindor {
    let name = "Gryffindor"
    let characteristic = "Brave"
    let image = Image("Lion")
}

struct Slytherin {
    let name = "Slytherin"
    let characteristic = "Cunning"
    let image = Image("Snake")
}
```

Now if I wish to have a wizard struct as follows, but I don't know how to include a House property within, such that when I try to create an instance of a wizard, I can call the properties from their respective houses.

```
struct Wizard {
        let name: String
        var house: ?
    }

let harryPotter = Wizard(name: "Harry", house: Gryffindor)
```

Basically, I wish to be able to refer to harry's house using the harryPotter instance, as such:

```
print(harryPotter.characteristic) //should print "Brave"
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are mixing types with objects so you should have a type House

```
struct House {
    let name: String
    let characteristic: String
    let image: Image
}
```

And then use that in the Wizard struct

```
struct Wizard {
    let name: String
    var house: House
}
```

And now you create first a House object for the Wizard and then the Wizard object

```
let gryffindor = House(name: "Gryffindor", characteristic: "Brave", image: Image("Lion"))
let harryPotter = Wizard(name: "Harry", house: gryffindor)
```

or all in one call

```
let harryPotter = Wizard(name: "Harry", 
                         house:  House(name: "Gryffindor", characteristic: "Brave", image: Image("Lion")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use protocol & generics, like below. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
protocol House {
    var name: String { get }
    var characteristic: String { get }
    var image: Image { get }
}

struct Gryffindor: House {
    let name = "Gryffindor"
    let characteristic = "Brave"
    let image = Image("Lion")
}

struct Wizard<H: House> {
    let name: String
    var house: H
}

let harryPotter = Wizard(name: "Harry", house: Gryffindor())
```